# Crystal Report throwing exception on client machine

Tags: .net, wpf, exception, crystal-reports-2010

I am getting below exception **`'the type initializer for 'crystaldecisions.crystalreports.engine.reportdocument' threw an exception.`** on client machine when we generating report.

I am using VS 2010 (WPF), and CR 13.0.2000.0 version .one solution is we can install "CRRuntime_32bit_13_0.msi" on client machine but this is not a good approach because MSi's size is 70MB.

please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved using Merge Module instead of install Runtime on client machine.